# Android: Chronometer save state

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Android app the will record voice.
the chronometer view start once the user click on a button and stop once click again.

My problem is the state of the Chronometer, as if the user rotate the device during the record, the activity is rebuild again.

The solution of android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" in the Manifest is not for me, as the layout is different and as we know the above solution don't change the layout.

I believe that solution is to save the state of the chronometer, but I need suggestion and help from someone.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time since the question was asked, but I wrote a Chronometer Helper class, which helps in maintaining the state, using SharedPreferences. And it could be useful to someone.

Here's a link to the class  : [ChronometerHelper](https://github.com/ahmedrizwan/ChronometerHelper)

**How to use?**

- Create an instance of ChronometerHelper

  ```
  ChronometerHelper chronometerHelper = ChronometerHelper.getInstance(mChronometer, mSharedPreferences);
  ```
- Start/Stop/Pause Chronometer

  ```
  chronometerHelper.startChronometer();

  chronometerHelper.stopChronometer();

  chronometerHelper.pauseChronometer();
  ```
- Resume Chronometer (inside onResume method of your activity/fragment or anywhere)

  ```
  chronometerHelper.resumeState();
  ```
- Check if chronometer is running

  ```
  chronometerHelper.isRunning() //returns true if it is
  ```